# Springboot webflux reactor delete items from mongoDB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I use springboot + mongodb, and I am a beginer for webflux. I write code for CRUD. When I access delete ids in Controller, code not working because count alway return 0. Any one help me?

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Delete multi cities")
@DeleteMapping
public Mono<ResponseEntity<AtomicInteger>> deleteByIds(@RequestBody @NotNull Set<String> ids) {
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Flux.fromIterable(ids)
                    .flatMap((id) -> {
                        return cityService.findById(id)
                                .flatMap((c) -> {
                                    count.getAndAdd(1);
                                    return cityService.deleteById(c.getId());
                                });
                    });
    log.debug("count = {}", count);
    return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok(count));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flux is not be subscribed
you should try like this

```
return Flux.fromIterable(ids)
           .flatMap((id) -> {
            return cityService.findById(id)
                              .flatMap((c) -> {
                               count.getAndAdd(1);
                               return cityService.deleteById(c.getId());
                              });
                    })
          .then(Mono.defer(() -> {
           log.debug("count = {}", count);
          return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok(count));
         }));
```

Comment: Would u please explain it for me? I don't clear.

Comment: as I said before, your Flux has published but not yet subscribed.
`
Flux.fromIterable(ids)
                    .flatMap((id) -> {
                        return cityService.findById(id)
                                .flatMap((c) -> {
                                    count.getAndAdd(1);
                                    return cityService.deleteById(c.getId());
                                });
                    }); // need to subscribed here 
`
When you return Mono, in the block, the controller just subscribe the mono when you return